# Splunk "stats" command considers only a subset of the items

Tags: logging, splunk

When I do:

```
index="..." | search "needle:" 
| rex "expected field: *(?<field1>[A-Z]*) date: *(?<adate>[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9]{4})"
```

it correctly shows 10K+ logs, while when I try the aggregation as follows:

```
index="..." | search "needle:" 
| rex "expected field: *(?<field1>[A-Z]*) date: *(?<adate>[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9]{4})" 
| stats count(adate) by field1
```

it takes only one instance (or a few instances) of the `field1` items, like if all the other field1 instances don't count in the stats.

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The `stats` command will ignore field1 values for which 'date' is null.  What more can you tell us about the data?  I notice the `rex` command extracts a field called 'adate', but `stats` is counting 'date' - is that a typo?

Comment: Yes it's a typo of me simplifying the script... Sorry. There is always a 'adate' instance, no null and thousand records with valid values. It's only 'stats' command cutting out most of them...

Comment: What if you use `stats count by field1` instead?